# Set Default Report Library to save report in Report Builder

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, reporting-services

I would like to set default library in Report Builder to save report(.rdl) without users selecting Report library to save report. Is this possible ? Please advise.

Things i have tried,
Having library location in SaveLocation querystring in URL when user lanuch report builder.

Setting SharePoint Report library location in Report Builder options.

Thanks,
Ronak

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, as my testing, there is no available option to set the default library in Report Builder.